# How do I enable scrolling in the integrated terminal in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio, code

I'm trying to scroll with the integrated terminal and I'm getting a series of weird text that's showing up, like `^[[<64;57;24M]]` and it's not scrolling.

I'm on the most up to date mac with the most up to date vs code.

Where can I enable scrolling for VS code?

Comment: There's an answer for this on SO: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69543386/scrolling-in-the-integrated-terminal-using-the-mouse-wheel